# Sending tensors on-demand to other worker nodes in Distributed TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

For a Distributed TensorFlow environment with at least two worker nodes, I am trying to send a tensor from one worker node to another in an "on-demand" fashion. Ideally, the receiving worker node could block until it receives the tensor. I would like the receiving worker node to be able to use the tensor as if it were a regular tensor.

The worker nodes don't need to be in a cluster, but I imagine it would be easier to achieve this if they were in one.

I am curious as to whether this can be done using something like RecvFromRemoteAsync, but I am not sure how exactly this could used at a Python level.

In other words, I am trying to achieve:

At sending worker node:

```py
...
sendTensor(to=recv_worker, tensor) # where recv_worker is some IP and Port
...
```

Then, at the receiving worker node:

```py
...
# the next line would ideally block until the tensor is received:
received_tensor=recvTensor(from=send_worker) # where send_worker is some IP and Port
# do something with the tensor, e.g.:
print(received_tensor.eval())
...
```

Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow uses `RecvTensor` service to transfer tensor. There're `SendOp`, `RecvOp` related to this service.

- `SendOp` produce tensor and `RecvOp` try to retrieve tensor.
- `SendOp` is local, just compute and buffer tensor in rendezvous.
- `RecvOp` will make a `RecvTensor` request if tensor lives on remote worker (By calling `RecvFromRemoteAsync`)

See TensorFlow [architecture](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/architecture) for more details.

Python side just pass client graph to C++ core for computation and communication. In this way, to implement a true `SendTensor` Service, TensorFlow core should be modified.